# Spline path - prevent overshoot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interpolation, spline

I have a NavAgent that follows the mouse cursor. A line renderer draws the nav path from a fixed starting point to the cursor with some smoothing achieved by what - with my limited math brain - I understand to be a cubic Hermit spline, adapted from this great [Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cg_Programming/Unity/Hermite_Curves) page:

```
IEnumerator IDrawPath(Vector3 endPos)
{

    while (drawLine)
    {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1500))
        {
            transform.position = endPos;
            nav.SetDestination(hit.point);

            line.positionCount = numberOfPoints * (nav.path.corners.Length - 1);

            for (int j = 0; j < nav.path.corners.Length - 1; j++)
            {

                p0 = nav.path.corners[j];
                p1 = nav.path.corners[j + 1];

                if (j > 0)
                {
                    m0 = 0.5f * (nav.path.corners[j + 1] - nav.path.corners[j - 1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    m0 = nav.path.corners[j + 1] - nav.path.corners[j];
                }

                if (j < nav.path.corners.Length - 2)
                {
                    m1 = 0.5f * (nav.path.corners[j + 2] - nav.path.corners[j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    m1 = nav.path.corners[j + 1] - nav.path.corners[j];
                }

                pointStep = 1.0f / numberOfPoints;

                if (j == nav.path.corners.Length - 2)
                {
                    pointStep = 1.0f / (numberOfPoints - 1.0f);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
                {
                    t = i * pointStep;
                    position = (2.0f * t * t * t - 3.0f * t * t + 1.0f) * p0
                        + (t * t * t - 2.0f * t * t + t) * m0
                        + (-2.0f * t * t * t + 3.0f * t * t) * p1
                        + (t * t * t - t * t) * m1;
                    line.SetPosition(i + j * numberOfPoints,
                        position);
                }
            }
        }

        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    }
}
```

Sometimes the line 'overshoots' an optimal curve position and doubles back on itself:

[image]
[image]

I'd like the line to proceed smoothly round those corners instead.

From reading up on splines from various sources I gather this behaviour is correlated to the values of the tangents being calculated  (the variables M0 and M1 in this case). I have adjusted these without success; larger values cause the line to stray away from the path points (and increase the size of the overshoot), smaller values cause a 'knot' rather than a loop as the resultant positions are very close together.

I tried filtering out some of the extreme points, hoping this might lead to a smoother line by adding some logic to say if the angle of the next point is above a certain threshold don't add it to the line renderer positions but this yields some odd behaviour. I've tried filtering out points that are very close together, again leading to some odd results.

This is probably simple stuff for a math wizz but I'm all out of ideas. How can I avoid the line doubling back on itself. I've readthrough [Monotone cubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation) which seems promising but frankly it's way over my head. Can the calculation above be adjusted to do this, or do I need to look for another way?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @QandeelAbbasi - I changed the approach, instead of using a nav agent I raycast from the mouse position to the destination. If a raycast hit something other than the destination I altered the raycast direction by 5 degrees until a clear path was found. After passing the object raycast to the destination again. Why do you ask?